# jQuery "curtain" function - optimal solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to achieve a similar "curtain" effect as they have on http://nautil.us.

I wrote a script which is working just fine, here is my **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LXUmG/)**. The function looks like this:

```
  function curtain() {
    var windowHeight = $( window ).height();
    var scrollPosition = $( document ).scrollTop();
    var value = - ( windowHeight - 70 );
    var mainHeight = $( "#main" ).height();
    var bodyHeight = windowHeight + mainHeight;
    if (windowHeight - scrollPosition <= 70) {
      $( "#curtain" ).css({position: "fixed", top: value});
      $( "#main" ).css({position: "static", marginTop: windowHeight});
      $( 'body' ).height(mainHeight);
    }
    else {
      $( "#curtain" ).css({position: "static", height: windowHeight});
      $( "#main" ).css({position: "fixed", top: value, marginTop: windowHeight});
      $( 'body' ).height(bodyHeight);
    }
  }
  $( document ).ready(curtain);
  $( window ).resize(curtain);
  $( window ).scroll(curtain);
```

However, I'm not sure if that's the best way of doing it. The script has to be triggered on each window.scroll event and I'm afraid it's using too many resources even when simply scrolling. Isn't there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to throttle the event handler.

```
window.curtainTimeoutId = null;

function curtain() {

    window.clearTimeout(curtainTimeoutId);

    window.curtainTimeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        // ...
    }, 10);

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpmfz/)

Also, if you're using underscore.js, you can use its `throttle` method to achieve the same effect more succinctly.

Comment: Thank you! One little problem, though: the `#curtain` div doesn't have 100% window height right away, it stretches to the whole window only after scrolling. You can try by pressing Run button in the Fiddle.

Comment: I've updated my Fiddle so that the only difference is the throttling bit. Please have another look.

Comment: Additionally, you can use this plugin for throttling/debouncing in jquery without underscore. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/